# How to form the URL address of a WebService by looking at its settings in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I run an installer to install a WebService

To run a web service in `InternetExplorer` locally, it has a form like this:

```
http://localhost:2537/Service.asmx
```

Now my question is if I go to IIS for the installed webservice, How can I know what URL address should I enter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `wwwroot` folder it has created a virtual directory folder so it will be something similar to:

```
http://localhost/Name_Of_Virtual_Dicrecotry/NameofService.asmx
```